# Cloning the HBase table from a snapshot to another cluster via distcp

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I upgraded my cluster to hadoop 3.3.5 and hbase 2.5.3 and faced compatibility problems. `ExportSnapshot` tool does not work with this setup. MR job can't finish because of `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$GetFileInfoRequestProto cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:132)
```

As far as I know, it happens because of the incompatibility between versions of protobuf in the HBase classpath and the required version for Hadoop.

Then I looked for another way to copy tables to another cluster. I wondered what would happen if I copied snapshot to another cluster and cloned it there.

I tested copying snapshots to another cluster via dictcp:

1. Create a snapshot of a table: `hbase> snapshot 'mytable', 'mytable-snapshot-test'`
2. Distcp a snapshot to another cluster: `hadoop distcp hdfs://cluster1/hbase/.hbase-snapshot/mytable-snapshot-test hdfs://cluster2/hbase/.hbase-snapshot/mytable-snapshot-test`
3. Clone the snapshot copy to the new table on the second cluster: `hbase> clone_snapshot 'mytable-snapshot-test','mytable-snapshot-test-table'`

And it works! I have a copy of my table in the second cluster.

But I read this article: https://blog.cloudera.com/introduction-to-apache-hbase-snapshots-part-2-deeper-dive/ and got stuck on the cloning operation:

> When an administrator performs a clone operation, a new table with the table-schema present in the snapshot is created pre-split with the start/end keys in the snapshot regions info. Once the table metadata is created, instead of copying the data in, the same trick as with the snapshot is used. Since the HFiles are immutable, just a reference to the source file is created; this allows the operation to avoid data copies and allows the clone to be edited without impacting the source table or the snapshot. The clone operation is performed by the master.

I don't understand how it works in my case when I have snapshots on another cluster.

Does HBase copy HFiles? Is it safe to copy snapshots and clone them in another cluster? Does HBase move or delete HFiles during compaction if snapshots are stored on another cluster?